# how to search for a string in a string array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

say i have the following:

```
string myArray[] = { "adam", "aaron", "brad", "brandon" };

cout << "Please type a name: ";
```

i want it so when a user types "bra" and hits enter, the program returns

```
brad
brandon
```

if the user types "a", the program returns

```
adam
aaron
```

if the user types "adam", the program returns

```
adam
```

I have tried strstr, mystring.compare(str), mystring.compare(x, n, str) - i can't find anything that is working.

what function would be the best way of handling this operation?

Comment: You said you've tried various things but you haven't actually shown why they don't work, your issue is probably in how you are attempting to use those functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great time for lambdas and [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). Assuming the string you want to find is named `to_find`:

```
std::copy_if(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray),
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
             [&](const std::string& s){
                 return s.find(to_find) == 0;
             });
```

Specifically, the way to test if some string `a` contains another string `b`, we can do:

```
a.find(b) == 0
```

[`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns the index at which `b` is found, or `npos` if it's not found. We want `0`, since you only want prefixes. We then wrap that in a lambda and pass it into `copy_if`, which will copy every element which passes our predicate and writes it to the output iterator we provide - in this case an `ostream_iterator<std::string>` which writes to `std::cout` and uses `\n'` as a delimeter.

To write out the same without C+11 would look something like:

```
const size_t size = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(*myArray);
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (myArray[i].find(to_find) == 0) {
        std::cout << myArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: do i need a certain header for this?

Comment: @user3571392 Check out the references I linked to, it's a good site to familiarize yourself with. For your specific question: you'll need `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your list of names is going to be, it can quickly become very slow to scan through the whole thing. You might want to look into implementing your own [prefix tree (aka trie)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).